# "Search" not working in Open office Calc (*.xls)

Tags: search, openoffice

I can't find any strings in the open office calc(version 3.2.1 in windows) document (*.xls) by doing a search(Ctrl+F).I tried with all options and then also i didn't get any positive result.

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: [please don't sign off each and every past with your (nick)name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed). Also, what're you searching for ? Examples ? Screenshots ?

Comment: Ok.thanks. In my xls, when i do a search for word "code" , it will not hit..even when the document contains 1000 times the word "code"

Comment: Do you have formulas in your spreadsheet ? Have you checked the option to see if search is checking formulas too ?

Comment: yes. i have selected the "formulas" for search

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Open Office Calc(*.ods)(version 4.0.1). The result when searching for a string I could clearly see was always "Search key not found".
 Solved when I realised I had ticked "entire cells"in "Find & Replace" for a particular purpose, and then forgotten to untick it.